# RX syntax to wait until particular value is received, take that, and then unsubscribe?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I am waiting for a particular value in a stream, at which point, I want to do some work in my subscriber and also unsubscribe from the ongoing stream.  What is the best syntax for doing that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var value = stream.Where(/* predicate to select value of interest */)
                  .Take(1)
                  .Subscribe(value => /* do work */);
```

Comment: You could consider FirstAsync() or FirstOrDefaultAsync() but Take() handles the case where the stream OnCompletes before a value of interest appears. Which is best will depend on your scenario.

Comment: Ha how did I miss that!?  Thanks

Comment: It's always easy once you know the answer! ;)